# Duplicate tags [karaf] and [apache-karaf]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tags [karaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/karaf) and [apache-karaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-karaf) are duplicates of each other and should be merged.

```
[karaf]        : 415 questions
[apache-karaf] : 759 questions
```

[apache-karaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-karaf) should be the primary tag because it is more precise.

Comment: I have voted (+1) for the synonym, but today, I see only 1/5 vote :-) Every question [karaf] are tagged [apache-karaf] too